# Vue 3 - Can't get the params value on route change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am calling this funciton

```
chooseProject(e) {
    let token = this.extractFirstText( e.title );
    let userId = this.projects.user_id;
    
    this.$router.push('/dashboard/'+token );
    localStorage.setItem( 'lastProjectToken_'+userId, this.projects.name + ' ('+token+')');
},
```

When I change the HTML select options:

```
 <v-select
    v-model="selectedItem"
    label="title"
    :options="option" @input="chooseProject"
/>
```

As you can see that it's going to this URL: `dashboard/---a token ----` page

This route is already defined:

```
{
    path: '/dashboard/:token',
    name: 'select-project',
    component: () =>
        import ('@/views/apps/projects/project-select/SelectProject.vue'),
},
```

So, when I first change the select option then on `SelectProject.vue` page I can get the `token` value but after that If I change the select option I can't get the `token` value.

**SelectProject.vue page:**

```
created() {  
     let _this = this;
    _this.projectToken = _this.$route.params.token;
    // data
    console.log( 'token is = ' + _this.projectToken );
    _this.$http.get("/ecommerce/data").then((response) => {
        _this.data = response.data;

        // ? Your API will return name of logged in user or you might just directly get name of logged in user
        // ? This is just for demo purpose
        const userData = getUserData();
        _this.data.congratulations.name = userData.username;
    });
},
```

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Note: I am new in Vue JS :)

Answer (score 1):

get params in vue 3 with composition API

Step 1

```
import { useRoute} from "vue-router";
```

Step 2

```
const route = useRoute();
```

step 3

```
route.params.token
```

Comment: At first call I can get the token but I can't get the token after the first call?

Comment: yes because you have added you code in created lifecycle hook that is run only once when page rendered.

Comment: Okay. I have changed it to `mounted` but still I can't get the value after first call.

Comment: it should be in watcher.

Comment: Please check this https://codeshare.io/N30dWr. I can't set the `projectToken` value.

Comment: In watcher I can't set the value.

Answer (score 0):

To get params in vue v3 with vue-router v4.x, in created lifecycle hook.

In your main.js file,
**instead of using**

```
app.mount('#app')
```

**change to this**

```
 router.isReady().then(() => {
  app.mount('#app')
})
```

It's work for me, Hope this could help.

Example code of main.js

```
import {createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import { createRouter,  createWebHashHistory} from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/dashboard/:token',
    name: 'select-project',
    component: () =>
        import ('@/views/apps/projects/project-select/SelectProject.vue'),
}
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
})

const app =  createApp(App)

app.use(router)
app.use(RouterLink)

// app.mount('#app')

router.isReady().then(() => {
  app.mount('#app')
})
```